# how get return of forEach in angular 2?

Tags: javascript

I do not know if the question should be directed to typescript or angular 2

how get return of forEach in angular 2?

I have the following:

```
let info = this.array.forEach((i, index) => {
    .....
    .....
    return res;

});

console.log(info);
```

Has returned -> undefined

Does anyone know how to get this return?

Comment: use `.map`. instead.

Comment: There's no such thing as a return of [`forEach`, as the documentation shows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control). Or rather, you are getting the one and only return value, `undefined`.

Comment: Foreach is used to carry out side effects, not return values. Use `map` to map one array to another using a function, which seems to be what you're trying to do here.

Comment: *I do not know if the question should be directed to typescript or angular 2* Neither. It's plain old JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript array comes up with inbuilt function called map, filter etc..So you can use map to iterate through values in array.

```
 let info = this.array.map((res,key) => {
        //key can also be accessible
        return res;

    });

    console.log(info);
```